# Why does the chat bar show up when I right click on Minecraft P.C.?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am on P.C. and have been playing Minecraft recently. I play on the ihascupquake oasis mod and for some reason when I tried to right click the chat bar came up in the bottom of my screen so I pressed enter and it went away. I pressed another several times and the same thing happened (The chat bar came up when  right clicked.). In that time I couldn't break blocks as you can't do anything when chat bar is up. I went into chat settings and selected "Chat bar: Hidden" and the chat bar went away but I still couldn't break blocks. I left the game and came back several times - no change. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Check in the controls that the right click isn't allocated to chat

Answer (score 1):

You shhould go into options and see what keys you have set for all the basic controls and reset them all back to normal.

Once you do that, "T" should be set for chat, right click should be for place and left click for break. My younger brother once had this problem and doing this fixed it.